# domDocument extract data

Tags: php, domdocument

I have a very simple code with domDocumet, but it has a mistake I can't solve:

```
 function getTagXML($mensaje, $tagname){

          $dom = new domDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
          libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
          // load the html into the object ***/
          $dom->loadHTML($mensaje);

          //discard white space
          $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
          $nodeList= $dom->getElementsByTagName($tagname); // here u use your desired tag     
          $node = $nodeList->item(0);

          $item = trim($node->nodeValue);
          libxml_clear_errors();

          return $item;
 }
```

I got the error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in line 82:
```

The line 82:

```
$item = trim($node->nodeValue);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message means that `$nodeList` isn't an object, which means that `$dom->getElementsByTagName($tagname)` returned `NULL`.

Based on [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166296/domdocument-tag-not-found) I would assume that this happens because your XML document is malformed, that is it's missing a root node.