# domDocument tag not found

Tags: php, domdocument

I have a function to look for XML tags:

```
 function extraerTagXML($mensaje, $tagname){


          $dom = new domDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
          //
          // load the html into the object ***/
          $dom->loadHTML($mensaje);

          //discard white space
          $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
          $nodeList= $dom->getElementsByTagName("'".$tagname."'"); // here u use your desired tag

          $items = array();
          for($i=0; $i < $nodeList->length; $i++) {
                    $node = $nodeList->item($i);
                    $items[] = trim($node->nodeValue);
          }
          var_dump($items);
         // libxml_clear_errors();

          return $items;

 }
```

When I execute:

```
    echo $salida;

    $resultado = extraerTagXML($salida,"MSG");
```

I got:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<cod_avis>3000082</cod_avis>
<MSG>ok</MSG> 
</Status>

array(0) {
}
```

So the "MSG" tag wasn't found. why?

Comment: Why use `domDocument` when `SimpleXML` is more suited?

Comment: Your XML document has no root node. You have a closing `</Status>` tag, but no opening one.

Comment: Also, you use `loadHTML` when you deal with XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're loading an XML document and not an HTML one. So use `loadXML()` instead of `loadHTML()` method.
Second, you don't need to append explicitly quotes around the tagname when calling `getElementsByTagName()`, so instead of

```
getElementsByTagName("'".$tagname."'");
```

use

```
getElementsByTagName($tagname);
```

Also as I mentioned in my comment above, your XML document isn't well formed - it's missing a root node, edit it to look like

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<Status>
<cod_avis>3000082</cod_avis>
<MSG>ok</MSG> 
</Status>
```

And third, you could also use [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) for the same purpose, since you're using `DOMDocument`, i.e.

```
$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$result = $xPath->query('//MSG');
echo $result->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

But that's just on a side note ;-)

Comment: That is still your DOMDocument object